# Showing Gamecenter on an exported Unity Xcode project

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center

I have an iOS Unity project which has been built and now I have a Xcode project. Now I want to Implement Gamecenter but I just can't seem to find the rootviewcontroller to show the GKLeaderboardViewController. On a native app, I would simply do the following:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *_delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[_delegate.viewController presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
```

But Unity messes up the code and I only have an AppController.h and an AppController.mm

Anyone has managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking inside the AppController.mm you can find:

```
if( [_window respondsToSelector:@selector(rootViewController)] )
    _window.rootViewController = controller;
```

So you can get root view controller by calling

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController]
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about keyWindow property.